# blender does freeze after some time, it uses 100% cpu time, but does nothing

Tags: modeling

I have updated to blender4 on linux mint and now blender freezes most of the time, top shows it uses 100-104 % cpu time - I have 4 cpus,  but it does nothing. I can not move an item, I cannot change the selected object, nothing at all. I cannot even quit blender correctly, I have to kill the process.
Can anybody explain what happens, what do You need to corner the bug?
Thanks,
Siegfried
( it is a rather simple mesh, only some cubes and cylinders and a torus )

Comment: This does sound like a bug, in which case it would be off-topic here on BSE, sorry. Just to make sure it's not configuration the folks here could actually help you do something about, please run Blender from a terminal, to see if it has anything to tell you.